# How can I take any function as input for my Scala wrapper method?

Tags: scala, function, methods

Let's say I want to make a little wrapper along the lines of:

```
def wrapper(f: (Any) => Any): Any = {
  println("Executing now")
  val res = f
  println("Execution finished")
  res
}

wrapper {
  println("2")
}
```

Does this make sense? My wrapper method is obviously wrong, but I think the spirit of what I want to do is possible. Am I right in thinking so? If so, what's the solution? Thanks!

Answer (score 29, accepted):

If you want your `wrapper` method to execute the wrapped method inside itself, you should change the parameter to be 'by name'.  This uses the syntax `=> ResultType`.

```
def wrapper(f: => Any): Any = {
  println("Executing now")
  val res = f
  println("Execution finished")
  res
}
```

You can now do this,

```
wrapper {
  println("2")
}
```

and it will print

```
Executing now
2
Execution finished
```

If you want to be able to use the return type of the wrapped function, you can make your method generic:

```
def wrapper[T](f: => T): T = {
  println("Executing now")
  val res: T = f
  println("Execution finished")
  res
}
```

Answer (score 2):

In your case you are already executing the function `println` and then pass the result to your wrapper while it is expecting a function with one arguments (`Any`) and that return `Any`.

Not sure if this answer to your question but you can use a generic type parameter and accept a function with no arguments that return that type:

```
def wrapper[T](f: () => T) = {
  println("Executing now")
  val res = f() // call the function
  println("Execution finished")
  res
}

wrapper {
  ()=>println("2") // create an anonymous function that will be called
}
```